# Defining methods in Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm trying to define a method inside a migration, but I'm getting an undefined method error:

```
undefined method 'do_something_specific' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0x4868018>
```

I'd rather not define it elsewhere, because it doesn't really relate to the rest of the application, just this specific migration.

To be clear, my migration looks something like:

```
class DoSomethingSpectacular < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    do_something_specific(1, 2)
  end

  def self.down
  end

private

  def do_something_specific(p_1, p_2)
    # something happens here...
  end

end
```

Am I missing something here?  Why can't I define this like this?

Answer (score 10):

As you may see from the error message the code isn't called from within your migration class but inside the connection adapter. I'm not sure, but this small change should work:

```
class DoSomethingSpectacular < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    DoSomethingSpectacular.do_something_specific(1, 2)
  end

  def self.down
  end

private

  def self.do_something_specific(p_1, p_2)
    # something happens here...
  end

end
```

Note that I made your method static and called it in a static way. This should overcome any class scope issues.

Comment: Yeah I didn't understand what it was calling it from within the adapter, but I figured it should still be within it's scope.  Anyway, now I get an error undefined method 'do_something_specific' for Class:Class

Comment: D'oh sorry. As `self.up` is a static method itself, the call to `class` will return `Class` and not `DoSomethingSpectacular`. I updated the sample code.

Comment: I think you can safely remove the 'DoSomethingSpectacular.' in self.up