# How to run a data-modifying migration that uses strip_tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, strip-tags

I'm adding a new column, `summary`, to an existing table. It will contain a plaintext snippet of the HTML from the column `body`.

I want to create summaries for all existing emails when I run my migration. However, I can't figure out how to use strip_tags within my migration.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class AddSummaryToEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  self.up
    add_column :emails, :summary, :string, :limit => 100

    Email.reset_column_information
    Emails.all.each do |email|
      email.update_attributes(:summary => strip_tags(email.body))
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Of course, this doesn't work:
`undefined method 'strip_tags' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter:0xb6e29be8>`

How can I access the strip_tags method within my migration? I know I can run a regexp or another such workaround but am still keen to find out how to do this for future usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `strip_tags` is an ActionView method and your migration inherits from ActiveRecord, it can't see the ActionView methods.

You can get to them this way, though:

```
def self.up
  ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags("<b>TEST</b>")
end
```

If you try including the ActionView variant, you'll get `undefined method 'full_sanitizer'` because you need to extend the class methods, and so on.  Much more of a pain.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I did try including `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` and got stuck. * Goes back to Ruby OO 101 :) *

Answer (score 1):

Because strip_tags is out of scope. You don't have access to ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper.
See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484302/defining-methods-in-rails-migrations)

Answer (score 1):

**wesgarrison**'s solution didn't work for me with Rails 2.3.5 version, so in order to make it work I had to directly call HTML sanitize method from the HTML::FullSanitizer module in the migration like this:

```
def self.up
  HTML::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize('<p>Test</p>')
end
```

Hope this helps someone who has the same problem as me.

Comment: Both worked for me with Rails 3.2.13 but this one seems to be the better one.